# How to variably choose a cell reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to reference a cell in an Excel formula.  However, I want the row number to be based on a cell value in another cell.  For example, I don't just want to reference cell R2, I want to say, reference the cell that is in column R, and has the row value I have listed in column V2.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you provide some sample data and the output you would like to see?

Answer (score 4):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(R:R,V2)
```

This will return the value of the cell in Column R and the row number that is entered in V2.

Answer (score 1):

the indirect formula should do it:

```
=indirect("R"&V2)
```

Comment: One note on INDIRECT, it is volatile and will recalc every time Excel recalcs.  Having one or two will not impact the calc times but many will.  Otherwise this is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

just to give out options.  `OFFSET` which is a volatile function will pick and return cells or ranges based on a given cell.  Volatile function will recalculate anytime anything on sheet changes.  Non-volatile functions only recalculate when when cells that affect them change.  Therefore a lot of volatile functions on a sheet can cause an unnecessary amount of excess calculations.  `INDEX` is the better solution.

`OFFSET` take the following form

```
OFFSET(BASE CELL, HOW MANY ROWS TO MOVE DOWN, HOW MANY COLUMNS TO MOVE OVER, HOW MANY ROWS TO RETURN, HOW MANY COLUMNS TO RETURN)
```

In your case I would be tempted to make the formula look as follows:

```
=OFFSET($R$1,V2,0,1,1)
```